# Exibir manytomany no list_display no django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando exibir alguns itens contantes no manytomany no list display no django, porém está retornando um erro, seguem os códigos:

**Models.py**

```
class Apenso(models.Model):

usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
processo = models.OneToOneField(Processo, blank=True, default=None)
apensos = models.ManyToManyField(Processo, blank=True, default=None, related_name="Apensos")

def __unicode__(self):
   return unicode(self.apenso) or u''
```

**admin.py**

```
class ApensoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('processo', 'get_apensos', 'usuario')
list_display_links = list_display
list_per_page = 30
search_fields = ('processo', 'requerente__nome')

show_change_link = False

def get_apensos(self):
    return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.apenso.all()])
```

E o erro exibido é:

```
Exception Value:    
get_apensos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Man, basicamente ele ta reclamando que foram passados dois argumentos para a função "get_apensos()", quando na verdade ela só espera um. Tem certeza que ta quebrando nesta parte do código?

Comment: dei uma verificada aqui, e so tem get_apensos nessa parte do codigo, nao tem em outro lugar

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja buscando por algo parecido com:

```
def get_apensos(self, obj):
    return ", ".join([str(p) for p in obj.apensos.all()])
```

Isso porque acredito que você quer listar os apensos da instância do objeto `Apenso`, estou certo?